# Link on enum in class

Tags: typescript, enums, ecmascript-6

I have a structure

position.utils.ts

```
enum PositionDirectionEnum {
    LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, AUTO
}

export class PositionUtil {
    public static PositionDirection: PositionDirectionEnum
}
```

utils.ts

```
import { PositionUtil } from "./position.util";
export class Utils {
    public static Position: PositionUtil = PositionUtil;
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
Utils.Position.PositionDirection.LEFT
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it should work

Comment: If it's work, I am not asking =)
I use WebStorm and him don't like this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

1) Drop position.utils.ts

2) In your utils.ts:

```
export namespace Utils 
{
    export namespace Position
    {
        export enum PositionDirection 
        {
            LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, AUTO
        }
    }

    export class Layout
    {
        public static Vertical = "vertical";
        public static Horizontal = "horizontal";
    }
}
```

3) In your file.ts:

```
import { Utils } from "./utils";

let p = Utils.Position.PositionDirection.LEFT;
let l = Utils.Layout.Horizontal;
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I forget about namespaces!(